# I have a problem connecting to the database

Tags: mysql, laravel

enter image description here

[image]

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
(SQL: select * from `admins` where `email` = ahmed@gmail.com limit 1)
http://localhost/project/test1/public/admin/login

can you help me

Comment: Have you started your mysql server in Xampp?

Comment: could you add your error message and code as text and provide some context, because it seems that you run a select with out establishing the connection prior.

Comment: @mmabdelgawad  yes i started and i open phpmyadmin

Comment: – nbk i use laravel so i can't add error message

Comment: please add more details, such as your .env file or database configurations

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 1):

Here are several things to check

1. Check you .env files and check the DB_CONNECTION, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD. Are the values for them is correct or not.
2. You can't add space in .env files. Example DB_PASSWORD =secret. Check for this too.
3. Check your mysql server status in XAMPP. You can restart the service if you want.
4. Check for database, tables and columns in your phpmyadmin, maybe you haven't migrate / create the database, tables and/or columns.

From your query I think it is correct already and you have use the correct naming convention. Maybe you can check the 4 points that I've mentioned.

Good Luck :)